# Add lines with 0 for missing values in a datatable

Tags: bash, unix, awk, datatable

I have a dataset counting occurences of bins, for instance:

```
1 10
2 15
3 1
5 50
8 990
```

As you can see, I am missing bins in the first column. As I want to plot this data, I'm looking for a way to add those missing value, with a 0 on the second column, e.g. if I know my bins go up to 10:

```
1 10
2 15 
3 1
4 0
5 50
6 0
7 0
8 990
9 0
10 0
```

I'm looking for a unix/bash solution as it fits my pipeline and my files are rather big, but maybe R is more suited for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Thanks to karafaka sir, adding solutions which will capture very first line's digits too.

```
awk -v value=10 '$1-prev>1{while(++prev<$1){print prev,"0"}} {prev=$1;print} END{if(prev<value){while(prev<=value){print prev,"0";prev++}}}'  Input_file
```

Let's say following is the Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
3 10
4 15
7 1
9 50
19 990
```

Then after running above code we will get following output.

```
1 0
2 0
3 10
4 15
5 0
6 0
7 1
8 0
9 50
10 0
11 0
12 0
13 0
14 0
15 0
16 0
17 0
18 0
19 990
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v value=10 'prev && $1-prev>1{while(++prev<$1){print prev,"0"}} {prev=$1;print} END{if(prev<value){while(prev<=value){print prev,"0";prev++}}}' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -v value=10 '
prev && $1-prev>1{
  while(++prev<$1){
    print prev,"0"
  }
}
{
  prev=$1
  print
}
END{
  if(prev<value){
    while(prev<=value){
      print prev,"0"
      prev++
    }
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: It's clearly working as I wish for my reproducible example as well as on real data. Thanks !

Comment: this will miss filling in the first records if missing.

Comment: @karakfa, thank you sir, I have added EDIT solution now which should work for very first line's miss too, kindly do let me know if anything missed here too, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Using Bash and `join`:

```
$ join -a 1 --nocheck-order -e 0 -o 1.1,2.2 <(seq 10) file
```

Output:

```
1 10
2 15
3 1
4 0
5 50
6 0
7 0
8 990
9 0
10 0
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Just doing my share, sir.

Comment: This is what I same up with as well. You might want `seq 10` instead of the `echo` process sub.

Comment: @glennjackman Yeah, that was a quick hack that caused more harm than good.

Answer (score 4):

we can combine `seq` and `awk` to make the task easier:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print $1 in a?a[$1]:$1 FS 0}' file <(seq 10)
```

You can do this as well:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print $1 in a?a[$1]:$0}' f <(seq -f '%g 0' 10)
```

Test with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
1 10
2 15
3 1
5 50
8 990

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print $1 in a?a[$1]:$1 FS 0}' f <(seq 10)
1 10
2 15
3 1
4 0
5 50
6 0
7 0
8 990
9 0
10 0
```

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v mx=10 '{while(++k<$1) print k,0}1; 
            END {while(k++<mx) print k,0}' file
```

this will fill the first records if missing as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{n[$1]=$2} END{for (i=1;i<=10;i++) print i,n[i]+0}' file
1 10
2 15
3 1
4 0
5 50
6 0
7 0
8 990
9 0
10 0
```

Comment: Ed, you are an old member, you know that adding explanation to an answer adds to its value :)

Comment: @Ibo no, sometimes it detracts from its value. Adding an explanation to a trivial script is as useful as adding an "increment i" comment to code that does `i++`. Anyone reading this who doesn't understand it will get vastly more from looking up the constructs in the awk man page than they would from me explaining "`for ...` is a loop" and so on.